# Pull external data into model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC. I went through the getting started guide for MVC 5 by Microsoft and have some really basic understanding of how things work. What I am looking to do is create a view page which display data from my domain model and related data that is not part of the domain model (the related data is on another sql server which I am not inserting or updating records. It's just related data I can associate with the data in my domain model).

For simplicity lets say I have a domain model that includes:

Student with Id Firstname, LastName, CourseId
Course with Id, Name, Department, ExtraInfoId

and I want to create another "model" (not sure if model is the correct term for this)

ExtraInfo with ExtraInfoId, Time, Location

The ExtraInfo is related to the Course by ExtraInfoId. ExtraInfo won't be in the database I am creating or updating. It is a external database that I want to connect to and pull data out of for display purpose, exampe get a student's Firstname, the course taken and then any "ExtraInfo" related to the Course.

I hope this makes sense. Any information or some quick sample code would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Scroll down to the topic of a [custom `ViewModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes), whose _"object model is more optimized for consumption by the view – and which might look completely different from the underlying domain model object"_

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have two class, one for your model

```
public class Student{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public int CourseId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Department {get;set;}
   public ExtraInfo ExtraInfos {get;set}
}

public class ExtraInfo {
   public int ExtraInfoId {get;set;}
   public DateTime? Time {get;set;}
   public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

Then in you controller you valorize first the Student class, then the ExtraInfos property of the student class and return the student class to you view, as a viewmodel.

```
 var student = GetMyStudent(id); //method for accessing your student's data, could be linq with EF, or a httpclient call
 student.ExtraInfos = GetExtraInfo(id); //same 
 return View(student);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I will have a look and see what I can do with this.

Comment: Btw. What happens if ExtraInfo is not part of my domain model - it is from a external SQL database and i want to include the "ExtraInfo" for the student if it has any? This was really my main concern as I know how to relate data to each other that is part of the Model. But not sure how to include data that is outside of the Model.

Comment: In the method "GetExtraInfo" you can fetch your data from wherever you want, for example from a REST endpoint or a class library call. As long as the method return an object of the same type you won't have any problem and you'll get your Student with the ExtraInfo fill. You need to declare, on the student class, the ExtraInfo property field as [NotMapped]